# Which function replaced R2016a's svmtrain after deprecation?

Tags: matlab, svm

I used `svmtrain` in MATLAB R2016a, but now I'm using MATLAB R2019a. When use `svmtrain` like before I get an error that `svmtrain` does not exist.

What function replaced `svmtrain` in R2019a?

Comment: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/support-vector-machine-classification.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is two important function for classifiaction data in matlab. insted of svmtrain in older version of matlab we use fitcsvm() in 2020ver:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2019a/stats/fitcsvm.html
and here is replaced for svmclassify:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2019a/stats/classreg.learning.classif.compactclassificationsvm.predict.html

Answer (score 3):

`svmtrain()` was deprecated and removed from the toolbox, hence it no longer works in newer versions of MATLAB. The official replacement is a [suite of functions](https://mathworks.com/help/stats/support-vector-machine-classification.html). You'll have to select which one you need depending on the problem requirements.

Answer (score 1):

For one class SVM, it is `fitcsvm`